# Declaring properties before using them - best practice?

Tags: javascript

I always declare properties on objects if i know i will use them in my code at some point (To help other developers not be surprised when a new property gets added onto an object in debugging process and wonder where or why it has been populated):

```
var TestHelper = function(){
    var Test = function(){
        // Public:
        this.a = null; // string
        this.b = null;  // number
    }

    // Public:
    return {
        /*Test*/ TestFunction: function(str, num){
            var test = new Test();
            test.a = s;
            test.b = num;

            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

I can find it frustrating when i come across code like this:

```
var TestHelper = function(){
    var Test = {};

    // Public:
    return {
        /*Test*/ TestFunction: function(str, num){
            var test = new Test();
            test.a = s;
            test.b = num;

            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

or even harder (losing the javascript type that's helpful for debugging)

```
var TestHelper = function(){
    // Public:
    return {
        /*{}*/ TestFunction: function(str, num){
            return {
                a = s,
                b = num
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... because it makes it just that bit harder to understand fully what the original developer had in mind.

Ignoring my opinion,

- What are the various thoughts on this and why?
- Do big teams generally like to declare properties first to help other developers, or visa versa?
- Am i asking the right question or is there another point i am missing?

Comment: What's the close vote for :) I'll correct it.

Comment: declared the things at the place where it is needed.break script into small function so you can declared it on top like C,C++ has

Comment: I have not voted for -1 buts its coding basic for any languages

Comment: so @RIYAJKHAN, you are saying you prefer properties that are declared before use rather than dynamic assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Of course developers prefer things documented it's easier for them.

A good practice in Javascript is to avoid undefined value, so for this it's far better to initialize your objects with null value, or empty array or empty objects.

However you forget a thing with your last case -> this approach when possible is the best :

```
function Test(str, num){
    this.a=str;
    this.b=num;
    return this;
}
Test.prototype.method = function(a){...}//adding method to the object Test
var test = new Test("toto", 5);
test.method(a);//executing method
```

Comment: So you are saying you prefer properties that are declared before use rather than dynamic assignment?

Comment: Well in my example you only have the choice to construct the object with the properties defined, this is the best approach when you can have your value when you create the object. But let's say you have a 3rd property defined but that you can't have his value when instantiating the object, then yes it's better to declared it and initiazing it with a null value (or empty array for array) in the constructor and assign the value later on when it's possible.